# AngularJS routing with multiple ids

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have the same route provider with a fixed and/or undefined Id.

For example:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/workspace/:workspaceId', { ... });
```

but I would like to load the same view/controller/route for:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/workspace/:workspaceId/:id', { ... });
```

C# Web API2 handles this like:

```
[Route("api/workspace/{id?}")]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider):

> `path` can contain optional named groups with a question mark: e.g.`:name?`

So it would look very similar to Web API:

```
$routeProvider.when('/workspace/:workspaceId/:id?', { ... });
```